# Problem with kernel 3.11.0-19-generic in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, kernel

A few hours ago Ubuntu (13.10) notified me that an update was available. I installed it, and then Ubuntu told me to reboot. After rebooting I encountered a problem:

The login screen wasn't using the usual, native resolution of my monitor, but a smaller resolution.

After typing my password, the screen went black, with only the mouse cursor moving (and it still wasn't running at my monitor's native resolution).

I tried to reboot several times, but every time the screen went black.

Sometimes (not always), after typing my password, Ubuntu displayed an error window, with a message related to the keyboard. In the "details" section, there was something about "/usr/lib/ibus/ibus-ui-gtk3".

After a while, I decided to try booting with an older kernel version. So I forced grub to show up by editing the `/etc/default/grub` file, and running `sudo update-grub`.

Every time I use the latest kernel (3.11.0-19-generic), I encounter the same problem.

Every time I use the previous kernel (3.11.0-18-generic), it works.

How can I make it work with the latest kernel version?

Comment: If you've ruled out an installation error, as it sounds like you have, consider [reporting this as a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). Chances are you're not the only person caught out by it if it is.

Comment: You really don't have a choice but to keep using the kernel that works with your device. Thats why the old kernels are kept, for cases where new ones don't fit your machine.

You can try 3.12, It seemed the only one that is stable for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was another update yesterday, and now it works.

Here's what I can see in the history:

[image]

The problems started after the updates on Tuesday ("mardi", Apr 1 2014), and were solved after yesterday's updates ("jeudi", Apr 3 2014).